# Allowing 2 date types for an attribute in an XML schema

Tags: xml, date, schema

I have written an XML schema and one of the elements is date. Below is the section of the schema that defines date

```
<xs:element name="temporal">
    <!--start date and end date-->
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="date">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:attribute name ="date" type ="xs:date" use="required"/>
                    <xs:attribute name="dateType" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
                    <xs:attribute name="dateFormat" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

For the attribute
<xs:attribute name ="date" type ="xs:date" use="required"/>

I want to be able to have either type = "xs:date" or type = "xs:gYear" as some collections do not contain full YYYY-MM-DD formats. I attempted doing:

```
<xs:element name="date">
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:union memberTypes="xs:date xs:gYear" />
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

but this did not work and when I exported the excel form the YYYY date was stored as 1905-02-04. I do not really know if it is possible to have an "or" option with xml schemas? or a solution that allows the option of the two date types without having to have two separate elements?

Any advice or solutions would be helpful

Comment: I'm confused, if it's an attribute named "date" that has these two possible formats, why have you defined a union type for an element named "data"?

Comment: sorry that was a typo, meant to be date

Comment: Yes, but why are you defining an element rather than an attribute? I would have expected to see a definition of a named simple type, with the attribute declaration containing a reference to the named type.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want

```
<xs:simpleType name="date-or-gYear">
    <xs:union memberTypes="xs:date xs:gYear" />
</xs:simpleType>
```

and then

```
<xs:attribute name="date" type ="date-or-gYear" use="required"/>
```

Comment: Ah thanks, I will give it a go and see if that works.

Comment: Hi Michael, Where in the schema would I define the simpleType?

Comment: A question like that worries me, it's a bit like asking how to start the engine on a plane - if you don't know, this isn't the place to find out. If you're writing XSD (or any other language) you need to start with some kind of tutorial, which will answer such questions. But the answer is that it can appear anywhere as a child of xs:schema - though you may need to understand the concept of targetNamespace.